# NullReferenceException when raising event

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, events, nullreferenceexception

Here is the faulty code section :

```
JoinAccueilEventArgs jaea = new JoinAccueilEventArgs(this._user);
if (this._user==null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("user...");
}

if (this == null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("this...");
}

if (jaea == null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("jaea...");
}
Console.ReadLine();
JoinAccueilEvent(this, jaea);
```

I'm getting a `NullReferenceException` on the last line (`JoinAccueilEvent(...)`
But nothing in console..

So what is `null` here ??

```
internal static event JoinAccueilEventHandler JoinAccueilEvent;
internal delegate void JoinAccueilEventHandler(object sender, JoinAccueilEventArgs e);

private void JoinAccueilHandler(object sender, JoinAccueilEventArgs e)
{
    _callback.UserJoinAccueil(e.User);
}
```

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Comment: FYI, one "raises" an event, one does not "throw" an event. One "throws" exceptions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most probably `JoinAccueilEvent` is `null`, you should check it in typical way when using events:

```
if (JoinAccueilEvent != null)
   JoinAccueilEvent(this, jaea)
```

The problems comes from the fact that if nobody subscribes the event, it is `null`. You can overcome this by adding *do-nothing* handler by default:

```
internal static event JoinAccueilEventHandler JoinAccueilEvent = delegate {};
```

In this case, checking for `null` is not necessary as there is always at least one event subscriber.

Comment: oh, yes you got it .. Thanks you. Is there any reason ? I'm little confused about that. what i can have missed here ? EDIT : No subscriber, yep.. Thanks you !